# Gaussian LU and Crout's Method give me different answers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

My book -Numerical Method- said, The Crout's method (LU Decomposition) formula is given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
A&=
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12}& a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}& a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}& a_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\\
L&=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 0& 0 \\
l_{21} & 1& 0 \\
l_{31} & l_{32}& 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\\
U&=
\begin{bmatrix} 
u_{11} & u_{12}& u_{13} \\
0 & u_{22}& u_{23} \\
0 & 0& u_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\\
A&=LU\\
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12}& a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}& a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}& a_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ l_{21} & 1& 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32}& 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12}& u_{13} \\ 0 & u_{22}& u_{23} \\ 0 & 0& u_{33} \\ \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then i checked on some sites, i got different formula, that is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A&=LU\\
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12}& a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}& a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}& a_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} 
l_{11}& 0& 0 \\ 
l_{21} & l_{31}& 0 \\ 
l_{31} & l_{32}& l_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix} \, 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & u_{12}& u_{13} \\ 
0 & 1& u_{23} \\ 
0 & 0& 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

And, for the formula on my book, it generalized by :

$$u_{pj}=a_{pj}-\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}l_{pk}u_{kj}\quad \tag{
$\begin{align}
p&=1,2,3,\ldots,n\\
j&=p,p+1,\ldots,n
\end{align}$
}$$

And

$$l_{iq}=\dfrac{a_{iq}-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}l_{ik}u_{kq}}{u_{qq}}\quad \tag{
$\begin{align}
p&=1,2,3,\ldots,n\\
j&=p,p+1,\ldots,n\\
u_{qq}&\ne 0
\end{align}$
}$$

But it doesn't work to reduce

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 3& -1\\ 
4 & 4& -3\\ 
-2 & 3& -1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
b=
\begin{bmatrix} 
5\\ 
3\\ 
1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The result of Crout's Method for decomposition is

$$
L=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ 2 & 1& 0 \\ -1 & 3& 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \quad U= \begin{bmatrix} 2& 3& -1 \\ 0 & -2& -1 \\ 0 & 0& 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

And it's wrong, the result of this multiplication didn't match with $A$,

Look at $l_{32}$ (wrong cell result) and $l_{33}$, my book said it always $1$, but when i tried Gaussian LU Decomposition (Another Method of LU Decomposition) i got $l_{33}=-5$ which is the correct answer, that is :

$$L=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0& 0\\ 
2 & 1& 0\\ 
-1& -3& -5\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
U=
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 3& -1\\ 
0 & -2& -1\\ 
0 & 0& 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is that mean, Crout's method have a limitation or it doesn't work in special case like this?

So, should i always using the Gaussian LU (Ordinary LU Decomposition) instead?

Please help me, i'm tired typing this. I hope someone helps me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you are decomposing $A=LU$ and if

i) $L$ is lower triangular with all diagonal entries as 1, then it is Doolittle's decomposition.

ii) $U$ is upper triangular with diagonal entries as 1, then it is Crout's method.

In your case Doolittle method will give decomposition $A=LU$, where

$  
L=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

and $  
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & -1\\
0 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -5
\end{bmatrix}
$